# Calculate milliseconds in Excel from .NET Timespan

Tags: .net, excel, csv, timespan

A .NET tool exports timespan values into a .csv file in the following format:

`00:00:00.6887981`

I can't format the cells in excel correctly to calculate a sum or average with the data.

Is there a possibility to work in excel with this kind of data?

Comment: Can you work within 3 decimal places on the `AVERAGE` and `SUM`? Excel *will* calculate to a millisecond (e.g. hh:mm:ss.000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,8))+MID(A1,9,9999)/(24*60*60)
```

and then format **B1**

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, simply putting the value into a cell should suffice. Excel will round off to the millisecond.

Comment: @Jeeped  You are correct! I assumed the value in **A1** was *Text*